# Errors while seeing vars up to zero in If-else

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I've got problem with `UiTextField`.

It shows ,*Expected expression*, *Expression resolves to an unused property*, Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by `';'` errors.

I've implemented the function like this:

```
if var1 != nil && var2 != nil && var3 != nil {        
    self.var1.delegate = (self as! UITextFieldDelegate)
    self.var2.delegate = (self as! UITextFieldDelegate)
    self.var3.delegate = (self as! UITextFieldDelegate)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
} else {
    var1: Double = 0 // <- errors up here
    var2: Double = 0
    var3: Double = 0
}
```

If I delete the `var1` `error` goes to the line below.

Thanks for help

Comment: Unrelated but if you need to add `as! UITextFieldDelegate` then you forgot to add the conformance to your class. Remove those casts and update your `class` line to something like: `class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate`.

Comment: could you please upload your `UITextField Delegate` `func()` code!

Answer (score 0):

The `var1` variable is already defined on the class (or somewhere else). You cannot redefine a variable like this.

Comment: In other words, remove the `: Double` part of each line.

Comment: thanks a lot, but now I've got another error in each line: "Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'UITextField?'".

Comment: You want `var1.text = "0"`